# I am looking for a two way radio/device with constant contact

Tags: skiing, communication, radios

Hello, I am looking for a device to be in communications with another person while skiing without having to push a button. Exactly like a cell phone, but since phones don't work up where we ski looking for something else.

any ideas?

Comment: Hi. What have you looked into? DX and ebay sell things one doesn't know exist...

Comment: @Vorac What is DX?

Comment: @gerrit, dx.com, madeinchina.com etc. are a series of large Chinese online-shops with questionable quality, low prices and free worldwide shipping. Shopping there is close to gambling :D

Comment: @Vorac Wow, I didn't know things could be so cheap.  Perhaps not something one would want to rely on...

Comment: @gerrit, it's a gamble. Read the users comments - they are always truthful (or at least good-intended). And you are correct - the items there are not to be relied on, but insane deals do show up. E.g. I got a quality hobby boxing gloves for 1/2 of the price of the cheapest, provided locally. And, free shipping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a walkie-talkie / two-way radio / private mobile radio with voice control.

Normally, to communicate with a walkie-talkie, you need to press a transmit button.  Some models, however, have voice-control: they will automatically start transmitting based on voice input.  My friend and I used the [Midland G7 XTR](http://www.midlandradio.eu/midland_g7_xtr/product_en_216250.aspx), that includes this feature.  We did not use the voice control, so I don't know how well it works.  We were quite worried about battery lifetimes, and wanted to prevent our walkie-talkies from transmitting without need (there are other sounds in nature besides our voice).  In principle, though, walkie-talkie with voice control should be exactly what you need.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I will research that. Thank you for your time.